# basic_stringstream and its parent classes

Tags: c++, stringstream

Why is `basic_stringstream` is derived from `basic_iostream` and not  from `basic_istringstream` and `basic_ostringstream`?

What all gets derived from `basic_istringstream` and `basic_ostringstream` then?

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

Comment: Logically speaking, `basic_stringstream<T>` *is-a* `basic_iostream<T>`, and also *is-a* `basic_istringstream<T>` and `basic_ostringstream<T>`. So ideally it should have been derived from all three. However this is a bit impractical because of the dreaded diamond. Virtual inheritance would be needed. So it is derived from what is most useful. In most cases the ability to treat a `basic_stringstream<T>`  as a `basic_iostream<T>` is way more useful than the ability to treat it as either `basic_istringstream<T>`  or `basic_ostringstream<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the standard. They're not "base" classes, they're class templates. So they get specialized for a specific type. E.g.

```cpp
typedef basic_istringstream<char> istringstream;
```

See them all [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)

Comment: should I use istringstream instead of stringstream if I know I will only be reading and not writing to stringstreams?

Comment: @InQusitive that's up to you, there's no guide on that

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not sure how this answers the question. the diagram you linked just seem to agree with what OP said (Inheritance diagram). Template class can inherit without problem. (Besides, OP doesn't said `istringstream` at all. )

Comment: @appleapple I was answering the question "What all gets derived from basic_istringstream and basic_ostringstream then?". Nothing gets derived from them. He/ she/ they are actually asking 2 questions, which causes these kinds of problems. That's why we have the one question per question guideline.

Comment: @InQusitive yes, you should.

Comment: @JHBonarius As I read it. the *what* refers to `basic_stringstream`. IMO there is only 1 question here.

Comment: @appleapple  feel free to post what you think is a better answer

Comment: @JHBonarius I'd do if I want. but I'm probably not experienced with this area enough/old enough to speak/know the reason. IMO `@n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m`'s comment in OP's post says it pretty well.